# MVYMenuViewController: How to destroy a view controller which was instantiated from storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, instantiation, viewcontroller

I am using the MVYMenu with storyboards (XCode 5/iOS7). I had to modify the example which uses xibs. 
So far, it works, but I think I am leaking view controllers when instantiating a controller each time the user clicks on the side menu:

Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UINavigationController *navigationController;
UIViewController * mrViewController;

if (indexPath.row == 0) {

    mrViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mrViewController1"];

} else if (indexPath.row == 1){

    mrViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mrViewController2"];

} else if (indexPath.row == 2){

    mrViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mrViewController3"];

} else if (indexPath.row == 3){

    mrViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mrViewController4"];

}  else {

    mrViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mrViewController1"];

}

navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mrViewController];
[[self sideMenuController] changeContentViewController:navigationController closeMenu:YES];
```

}

When I monitor performance, memory usage grows each time I click a table cell to bring up a new scene. I think I have to destroy the previous present view controller somewhere in the above code, but I don't know how and where? I am new to iOS, coming from Android...

Comment: Are you using ARC?  And how do these `mrViewController` exist relative to the table view in which this code resides?  I'm not familiar with `MVYMenu`.  It's not part of vanilla Objective-C, and as far as I know it's not necessarily common, so some explanation of how it's supposed to work might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using storyboards, create a push segue(s) from your tableViewController to your detail view controller(s) and call those segues from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. This is the proper way of transitioning between view controllers with storyboards. It also happens to be a lot easier than what you are doing. If you're rows are static, you can even hook the segues directly to the rows and you won't have to do any programming at all!

Comment: One caveat to the last comment... you'll still have to dismiss the view controllers...

Comment: I am using storyboards, but the MVYMenu Component (which originally uses nibs), creates the TableView from a separate nib. Here is the code from the MVYMenuViewController: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
 
 [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MenuCell"];
 self.menuItems = @[@"Menu Item 1", @"Menu Item 2", @"Menu Item 3", @"Menu Item 4"];
}

Comment: Could I somehow make MVYMenu use storyboards, so that I can use the proper way with segues? (I love storyboards, Android doesn't have anything like that...)

Comment: You should be able to. Copy the content of your nib file and paste it into the storyboard. Change the viewController's class (if necessary) and link any IBOutlets or IBActions to your controller class.